# Restart a dummy application when testing rails engines?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm working in a new Rails engine and I need to restart it while testing. Of I try `Dummy::Application.initialize!` it do not work because the application was already initialized, so Rails returned the same instance.

I need to do so my engine `after_initialize` block runs again>

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that Rails::Application has any (at least publicly accessible) method for restarting the stack.  Your best way (and what I do) is just exit the server process (Control + C) and `rails s` the server back up.

If that is not what you are talking about, please be more specific on the error and situation you are in.

ref: http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.7/classes/Rails/Application.html

Comment: I'm testing if the middleware stack contains a specific Middleware, and this middleware to be loaded depends on a txt file on the rails root, so i need to be able to initialize! again the application to test with or without the txt file, got it ?

Comment: The middleware should already be loaded by the time `initialize!` is hit so that should be able to flag which strategy to execute for your own Application-level.